# FadeIn Add More link when a selection is made, otherwise hide it

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I made a dropdown menu that I want to clone on "add more" click. I only want that link to appear once a selection is made that isn't the default one.

Also, every cloned dropdown should not contain the option that is selected in the dropdown before it.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/eFR9w/)

So if I select "Show Add More (1)" on the first dropdown, the second dropdown should only have

```
<option value="3">Show Add More (2)</option>
<option value="4">Show Add More (3)</option>
```

left in it rather than all the options again (and of course get rid of the default option)

Here is my code:

```
     <div id="template">
    <select name="category0">
        <option value="1">Hide Add More</option>
        <option value="2">Show Add More (1)</option>
        <option value="3">Show Add More (2)</option>
        <option value="4">Show Add More (3)</option>
    </select> 
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="remove" onClick="removeFilterCat(this);">x</a>                                      
</div>
<div id="add_more_cat"></div>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="addFilterCat('template', 'add_more_cat');" id="add_more_text">+ Add more</a>

<script>
var filter_counter = 1;

function addFilterCat(divName, template) {
    if (filter_counter < 5) {
        var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
        newdiv.innerHTML = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
        newdiv.className = 'added';
        document.getElementById(template).appendChild(newdiv);
        filter_counter++;

        if (filter_counter == 5) {
            $("#add_more_text").css("display", "none");
        }
    }
}

function removeFilterCat(obj) {
    if (obj.parentNode.className == 'added') {
        obj.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(obj.parentNode);
        filter_counter--;

        if (filter_counter < 5) {
            $("#add_more_text").css("display", "inline");
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Please help me figure this out!

Comment: If you're using jQuery already, is there a reason why using vanilla javascript to select stuff? For instance `document.getElementById`

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean. And once the counter hits 5 I want the link to disappear, but I also want that link not to be there if nothing is selected from the first dropdown

Comment: `document.getElementById("add_more_text").style.display = 'none';` is vanilla javascript way of selecting elements and adding styles. This is jQuery's way: `$("#add_more_text").css("display", "none")`

Comment: ok I changed that, it does the same thing anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, this is what you need.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/eFR9w/6/)**

I changed the whole thing to use jQuery, since it was allowed and you were already using.

The code is cloning the previous element and removing the selected value, as requested.

Let me know if it helps!

```
$("#add_more_text").click(function () {

    if (filter_counter < 5) {

        var newdiv = $("<div>");
        newdiv.html($("#template").html());
        newdiv.attr('class', 'added');

        $("#templates").append(newdiv);

        var toRemove = newdiv.prev().children('select').find(':selected').val();

        newdiv.find("select option[value='" + toRemove + "']").remove();

        var a = newdiv.children('a').eq(0);
        a.on('click', function () {
            console.log(a);
            remove(a);
        });

        filter_counter++;

        if (filter_counter == 5) {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    }
});
```